# Speed Up tests without database interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've added some `:js => true` tests to my project and had to integrate the `database_cleaner` gem to make it work. Now my tests, even the one's that don't use a database are slowed down considerably. Is there a way to skip database access for mocked/non-db-based tests?

Relevant part of the **spec_helper.rb**

```
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatabaseCleaner only if it need

spec_helper.rb

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  if :without_db != example.metadata[:type]
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
end

config.after(:each) do
  if :without_db != example.metadata[:type]
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
describe User, :type => :without_db do
  it 'should be valid' do
    should be_valid
  end
end
```